# Connecting to the file systems of networked computers

Tags: remote, nautilus

At work, I am able to connect to all networked servers within the LAN simply by going to windows explorer and typing in the servers name or ip address, i.e.

`\\ip_address_here\c$` (can't remember if i use forward or back slashes)

that gets me straight into the c: drive of that server.

At home I have linux computers on the LAN.  All computers can ping each other without a problem.  How do I go about setting things up so I can do a similar thing as I do at work.

i.e. I want to simply be able to load nautilus and type in the ip address in the location bar

**UPDATE:**

I have Ubuntu and Debian computers on my LAN.

Comment: Realizing it is possible to do what you want using Samba, but I would consider it a major security hole to have the `/` or `c$` wide open to anyone via the network. Use caution when doing something like this. Yes it's convenient, but it's a dangerous setup to expose things in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

The service that you are going to need is Samba. It acts as an SMB File server, very similar to what Windows does. This is a nice and simple [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) for howto set it up on Ubuntu.

Basically you'll have to do the following steps:

- Install the Samba server on each computer from which you want to share data.
- Configure shares in the Samba server by editing `/etc/samba/samba.conf`.
- Restart the Samba service using `sudo restart smbd` and `sudo restart nmbd`.

Once you've setup Samba on each Linux system you'll be able to access whatever folders are shared via Samba like so through Nautilus:

```
 smb://user@server/share
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using autofs to automatically mount remote file systems (via nfs or smb your choice) when referenced.

if your mount point is in /net directory then you can access each host (after correct configuration) `ls -l /net/hosta/home` or `ls -l /net/hostb/var/www`

Search in google for autofs there's loads of examples for each distribution (you didn't mention what you are using). or look at the canonical [www.autofs.org](http://www.autofs.org/)

Comment: I have Ubuntu and Debian computers on my LAN.

Comment: Ubunto have a community document worth reading, then ask a specific question if you get stuck. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs